# Windows Shell Script "is was unexpected at this time." in Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, windows-scripting

Very new to this, so I apologize if this is something simple. I am running the following .bat script in Command Prompt for an assignment.

```
@ECHO off

TITLE "KnockKnock.bat - The KnockKnock joke game!"

COLOR 0E

CLS

ECHO.
ECHO.   
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.

SET /p reply="Knock Knock!    C:>"

CLS

IF NOT %reply% == "Who is there?" (
  ECHO "Sorry, but you are not playing the game right!"
  GOTO :EOF)

ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.

SET /p reply="Orange!         C:>"

CLS

IF NOT %reply% == "Orange who?" (
  ECHO "Sorry, but you are not playing the game right!"
  GOTO :EOF)

ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.

ECHO "Orange you glad you've written your first Windows shell script?"

ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
```

The script will prompt "Knock Knock!" as it should, but upon responding "Who is there?" (w/o quotations), I am presented with the error "is was unexpected at this time". What am I doing wrong?

Again, I realize this is probably very elementary, so I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when the `%reply%` variable is substituted with its value, cmd tries to interpret this:

```
IF NOT Who is there? == "Who is there?" (
```

Rather than this:

```
IF NOT "Who is there?" == "Who is there?" (
```

To fix it, add quotes around `%reply%`, like this:

```
IF NOT "%reply%" == "Who is there?" (
  ECHO "Sorry, but you are not playing the game right!"
  GOTO :EOF)
```

Comment: @user2480659 you need to test for "who's there?" and "whos there?" to cater for bad english.  Use the `IF /i NOT ...` syntax to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Thank you very much Blorgbeard. That fixed my issue.

Comment: I know this question is old, but I'm trying the same script, with the fix in this answer, and when I type `Who is there?` without the double quotes, I'm not getting the `ECHO` display. Not sure why it works for Jerry, but I'm not getting the error message. Any advice?

Comment: It's `IF NOT`, so you should get the `ECHO` for every input *except* `Who is there?`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I suggest you post a new question, anyway - you'll get more people than just me looking at it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Maybe I should. I just don't like posting duplicates. What the example Jerry and I are trying is saying what you said: If `"%reply%"` contains `Who is there?` and not `"Who is there?"`...meaning the user is required to include the double quotes when replying, then the error message fires. When I type `"Who is there?"`, the script continues on. When I type `Who is there?`, I get the command prompt, not the error message.

Comment: I suspect that if you post a new question, it won't be a duplicate, because your issue will be different to the one in this question. Can you cut your script down to the shortest snippet that shows the problem, and include sample input/output/expected output?