# Windows Shell Script no ECHO when "IF NOT %reply% ==" condition is met

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I'm working with the same Shell script as [Windows Shell Script “is was unexpected at this time.” in Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078631/windows-shell-script-is-was-unexpected-at-this-time-in-command-prompt). The solution here worked for Jerry (the requester) and helped me too until I tested for the `IF NOT` condition. Here is the code in question:

```
SET /p reply="Knock knock!  C:>"

CLS

IF NOT %reply% == "Who is there?" (
    ECHO "Sorry, but you are not playing the game right!"
    GOTO :EOF)
```

In Jerry's example, Blorgbeard offered the solution that `%reply%` should be surrounded by quotes so that it would would test for:

```
IF NOT "Who is there?" == "Who is there?"
```

Rather than:

```
IF NOT Who is there? == "Who is there?"
```

Which caused both Jerry and me to get the error: `is was unexpected at this time`.

After using Blorgbeard's solution, the error went away, but when I tried typing `Who is there?` instead of `"Who is there?"` to check the validation, the code skips past the validation `ECHO "Sorry, but you are not playing the game right!"`

What am I missing? Any advice?

Comment: The proper syntax is `IF /I NOT "%reply%" == "Who is there?" (` . The problem being though that any logical programmer would also consider allowing, `Who is there`, `Whos there`, `Whos there?`, `Who's there`, `Who's there?` too!

Comment: @Compo Why the `/I`? Please explain. And you're right. However, Jerry and I are testing code that someone supposedly already tested and put into a tutorial, so one would think the instructor already tested these. I'm finding that may not have been so.

Comment: Lou, to get usage information on an internal command, it is recommended to type that command at the prompt followed by `/?`, _(in this case `If /?`)_. The `/I` option means that you are comparing case insensitively, _this means that `wHo iS tHeRe?` is also an allowed response_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF NOT "%reply%" == "Who is there?" (
```

worked fine for me with your original code.

An alternative method to incorporate other valid responses might be:

```
for %%a in ("Who is there" 
            "Who is it"
            "Whos there" 
            "Who's there") do (
 if /i "%%~a"=="%reply%" goto valid
 if /i "%%~a"=="%reply%?" goto valid
)
ECHO "Sorry, but you are not playing the game right!"
GOTO :EOF
:valid
```

Note here that the list of items that are valid may be spaced across lines, as shown, but each item must be quoted as it contains spaces.

The placement of the parentheses is critical.

The `"%%~a"` item means take the value of `%%a`, remove any enclosing quotes, then re-apply the quotes. In this way, a response like `Qui` could also be accepted and specified within the list, but since it does not contain spaces, the item `Qui` can be *optionally* quoted.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last part of your answer, but I was wondering if white space and other syntax may not have been explained within the tutorial. It seems you are placing code on multiple lines instead of one, so I'm curious, if my code worked fine for you, why the same code isn't working for me?

Comment: I've no idea, I'm afraid. If you've copy-pasted this code - well, it works for me. Perhaps if you were to reveal what exactly "doesn't work" then the situation may become clearer.

Comment: I did give an example of what "doesn't work" in my original question (second to the last sentence referring to "After using Blorgbeard's solution"). If I type `"Who is there?"`, the code continues on. I'm under the assumption `Who is there?`, because there are no double quotes, would be different per Blorgbeard's solution. If I'm misunderstanding that and they are considered the same in shell script, then there's no issue.

Comment: Ah - if you are actually *inputting* the `"` characters, then you could insert `SET "reply=%reply:"=%"` on the line following the `set /p`. This would remove all `"` from the response. The script would then also approve `"Who "is" there"` for instance. Note that there was a small bug regarding the positioning of the `?` in the second `if`. Batch isn't particularly good at string-processing. There would be many input strings that would cause `cmd` conniptions.

Comment: Ok - So would that be the reason why, if I have the whole `IF` statement all on one line, and the `NOT` condition is met, I see `GOTO :EOF` printed at the end, but if it's all split out on separate lines like I have it in my example, it skips everything and goes directly to the end of the script? I'm not sure why I'm seeing issues, but others who try my code don't.

Answer (score 0):

As per Compo's hint to just check if the reply contains the words `who` and `there` case independent:

```
SET /p reply="Knock knock!  C:>"
CLS
If not defined reply goto :wrong
echo %reply%|find /i "who" 2>&1>Nul && echo %reply%|find /i "there" 2>&1>Nul && Echo goto :right
:wrong
ECHO "Sorry, but you are not playing the game right!"
GOTO :EOF
:right
```